# AWS IAM - Can you use multiple wildcards (*) in a value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

In all of the IAM Policy examples, they mention using wildcards (`*`) as placeholders for "stuff".  However, the examples always use them at the end, and/or only demonstrate with one wildcard (e.g. to list everything in folder "xyz" with `.../xyz/*`).

I can't find anything definitive regarding the use of multiple wildcards, for example to match anything in subfolders across multiple buckets:

> `arn:aws:s3:::mynamespace-property*/logs/*`

to allow something to see any `log` files across a "production" (`mynamespace-property-prod`) and "sandbox" (`mynamespace-property-sand`) bucket.

Comment: I can confirm that an IAM policy resource in the form of `arn:aws:cloudformation:*:123456789012:stack/Foo/*` works. This contains multiple wildcards, one of which is not at the end of the ARN.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Not sure, but "all of a sudden" (you know what I'm talking about) it's working in the [policy simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp) with:

- Policy 1: *"allow specific S3 permissions on any bucket"* **(e.g. an editor role)**
- Policy 2: *"deny all S3 actions unless in a user's folder across buckets"* **(i.e. can only see their files)**

Where 'Policy 2' is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ExplicitlyDenyAnythingExceptOwnNamedFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotResource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mynamespace-property*/subfolder/${aws:username}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

As a sidenote, be aware that `arn:aws:s3:::mynamespace-property*/${aws:username}/*` *(no explicit subfolder)* will match both with and without "intervening" subfolders:

- `arn:aws:s3:::mynamespace-property-suffix/subfolder/theuser/files..."`
- `arn:aws:s3:::mynamespace-property-suffix/theuser/files..."`

Answer (score 19):

**Yes, It will work**

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html):

> You can use wildcards as part of the resource ARN. You can use
> wildcard characters (* and ?) within ARN segments (the parts separated
> by colons) to represent any combination of characters with an
> askterisk (*) and any single character with a question mark (?). You
> can use multiple * or ? characters in each segment.

For those questioning the meaning of the single `*`. Do not interpret that as spanning multiple segments but rather that is has special meaning of `ALL RESOURCES`.

Worth noting you you cannot use a wildcard to match part of a principal name or ARN (if you are working with a [resource based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html)).

Comment: It's interesting the documentation specifies `...a wildcard cannot span segments.` - wouldn't the generic `Resource: "*"` (which, from what I understand, is valid) not be consistent with this statement?

Comment: @WXMan you bring up a good point. Personally, I interpret the `Resource: "*"` as an alternative to specifying an ARN, so the ARN wildcard documentation doesn't apply.

Comment: Strangely, the policy simulator seems to disagree with the documentation. Wildcards DO span segments (they really act like a `.*` regex). This could lead to serious security issues when overlooked.

Comment: I think we all misread the documentation, because it states that ARN segments are "the parts separated by COLONS" (as in: wildcards don't span over multiple ARN definitions in the list), not slashes. So there's really no reason `*` would not match any resource.

Answer (score 6):

The [ARN Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/qs-arn-format.html) is composed by segments (like **partition**, **service**, **regions**, ...):

```
arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resource-id
arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resource-type/resource-id
arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resource-type:resource-id
```

according to the documentation:

> You can use multiple * or ? characters in each segment, but a wildcard
> cannot span segments.

I interpret that like you can use many wildcards, but the ones you use in a segment (delimited by `:`) doesn't affect the other segments. So the answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use multiple wildecards anywhere wildecard is supported:

- https://steampipe.io/blog/aws-iam-policy-wildcards-reference
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html