# aws cli flag to test if user has all permissions for a task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I am using `aws ecs-cli up` command and want to restrict the role/group of the caller to the least privilege by using specific permissions.

Is there a flag or way to test run a cli command to validate if all required permissions are availabale to the caller, rather than say `iam:*`?

Additionally, is there a way to limit the permissions to partial wild-card resource, for example, below I have set `*` not knowing the full name in advance, so could I add `myecs-*` for example, that would restrict the resource to some degree?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1555577550000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateRole"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To validate, if all required permissions are available to IAM users, groups or roles in your AWS account. Following are some of the options;

1. Use [Web-GUI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/test-your-roles-access-policies-using-the-aws-identity-and-access-management-policy-simulator/) based [policy simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html) from AWS.
2. Use [simulate-principal-policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/simulate-principal-policy.html) aws cli command i.e. `aws iam simulate-principal-policy`. Furthermore, if you would like to cover [custom-policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/simulate-custom-policy.html) use aws cli command i.e. `aws iam simulate-custom-policy` .
3. Use python based [aws-iam-tester](https://pypi.org/project/aws-iam-tester/) command.

You can use wild-card within your IAM policy statements for Resource or a NotResource. Please refer following reference about same;

1. [IAM JSON policy elements - Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html).
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561731/aws-iam-can-you-use-multiple-wildcards-in-a-value) existing thread.

Comment: thanks for the details answer @amitd. The policy simulator assumes that you already know the policies that are actioned as part of the CLI call. I did not see a way in either the GUI or python script to simulate a CLI action without knowing the list of calls made. Am I missing something?