# how to add getObject public access to all folders in a S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I have a folder in a S3 bucket that contains many more folders, and I want to enable getObject public access to the object in all of those folders can I do something like?

```
{
  "Id": "example123",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "example123",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/next-level-folder/*/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

...where the first `*` is all the folders and the second `*` is all the objects in the folders?

I am going to have lots of folders that will require public access and don't want to have to write out the path for each one and put them in the resources e.g.

```
"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/next-level-folder/folder1/*",
              "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/next-level-folder/folder2/*",
              "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/next-level-folder/folder3/*",
             ]
```

Comment: This suggests that you can: [AWS IAM - Can you use multiple wildcards (*) in a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22563714/174777) Give it a try and tell us what you discover!

Comment: If you also want to allow access to objects such as `next-level-folder/dog.png` then simply use `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/next-level-folder/*` which will allow everything under the prefix `next-level-folder/`.

Comment: Awesome thanks, "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/next-level-folder/*"  did the trick, I was under the impression you needed the full path to the object but this is working, cheers.